# SVG и CSS анимация для иконки

Tags: css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

У меня есть две [иконки](https://jsfiddle.net/jxie/ga61c3zs/1/): одна в исходном состоянии, вторая  иконка перечеркнута.

Я хочу анимировать зачеркивающую линию, но изменение `dash-offset` не помогает, поскольку это два разных svg.

Я смотрю на [эти анимированные иконки](https://icons8.com/c/animated-icons), но все еще не могу понять волшебную часть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу спросить: Какой должен быть переходный процесс?
Я предпочитаю использовать `pure CSS`, возможно ли это?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [SVG line cross animation for icons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51219052/7394871) от участника  [@Mengo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5326588/mengo).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/51219052/7394871

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Анимированные иконки по вашей ссылке довольно сложны

Но в основном то, что они делают, это скользящая прямоугольная маска справа налево, которая покрывает первую иконку и открывает вторую иконку.

Вот упрощенная версия, использующая чистый CSS, который, надеюсь, делает ее более ясной.

```css
svg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

/* сдвигает две маски влево при наведении курсора */
svg:hover #bottom-rect,
svg:hover #top-rect
{
  transition: transform 500ms;
  transform: translate(-24px, 0px);
}

/* сдвигает две маски вправо, когда они не hovered */
svg #bottom-rect,
svg #top-rect {
  transition: transform 500ms;
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
    <defs>
        <mask id="bottom">
          <rect id="bottom-rect" width="24" height="24" fill="white" stroke="none"/>
        </mask>
        <mask id="top">
          <rect id="top-rect" x="24" width="24" height="24" fill="white" stroke="none"/>
        </mask>
    </defs>    
   
    <g mask="url(#bottom)">
      <path d="M12 1a3 3 0 0 0-3 3v8a3 3 0 0 0 6 0V4a3 3 0 0 0-3-3z"></path>
      <path d="M19 10v2a7 7 0 0 1-14 0v-2"></path>
      <line x1="12" y1="19" x2="12" y2="23"></line>
      <line x1="8" y1="23" x2="16" y2="23"></line>
    </g>
    <g mask="url(#top)">
      <line x1="1" y1="1" x2="23" y2="23"></line>
      <path d="M9 9v3a3 3 0 0 0 5.12 2.12M15 9.34V4a3 3 0 0 0-5.94-.6"></path>
      <path d="M17 16.95A7 7 0 0 1 5 12v-2m14 0v2a7 7 0 0 1-.11 1.23"></path>
      <line x1="12" y1="19" x2="12" y2="23"></line>
      <line x1="8" y1="23" x2="16" y2="23"></line>
    </g>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51230539/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>

Answer (score 4):

> Анимированные иконки по вашей ссылке довольно сложны

А если попробовать сделать анимацию иконки самостоятельно. Действительно ли это так сложно?

Например  попытаться анимировать `Running Infinity` [иконку](https://icons8.com/animated-icons/set/loader)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Создание анимации иконки по шагам:*

***Шаг #1.*** В векторном редакторе рисуем восьмерку и вычисляем полную длину контура - `getTotalLength()`

```html
<style>
.container {
width:10%;
height:auto;  
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 100 100">
   <path id="path" fill="none" d="M24.3 30C11.4 30 5 43.3 5 50s6.4 20 19.3 20c19.3 0 32.1-40 51.4-40C88.6 30 95 43.3 95 50s-6.4 20-19.3 20C56.4 70 43.6 30 24.3 30z"  stroke="#151515" stroke-width="10"  />
</svg>
<script>
console.log('Полная длина :' + Math.round(path.getTotalLength()) +'px')
</script>
```

***Шаг #2.*** Вырезаем часть контура с помощью `stroke-dasharray="202.75,54.25"`, где `54.25` -  пробел
**Обратите внимание:** если сложить цифры длин черты и пробела получится максимальная длина контура `257px`

```html
<style>
.container {
width:8%;
height:auto;  
background:white;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  
  <path fill="none" d="M24.3 30C11.4 30 5 43.3 5 50s6.4 20 19.3 20c19.3 0 32.1-40 51.4-40C88.6 30 95 43.3 95 50s-6.4 20-19.3 20C56.4 70 43.6 30 24.3 30z" stroke-dashoffset="27" stroke-dasharray="202.75,54.25" stroke="black" stroke-width="8" />
 </svg>
```

***Шаг #3.*** Добавляем анимацию вращения контура с помощью `stroke-dashoffset`

```
<animate  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="257; 0" begin="svg1.click" 
  dur="1s" restart="whenNotActive" repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

```html
<style>
.container {
width:8%;
height:auto;  
background:white;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  
  <path fill="none" d="M24.3 30C11.4 30 5 43.3 5 50s6.4 20 19.3 20c19.3 0 32.1-40 51.4-40C88.6 30 95 43.3 95 50s-6.4 20-19.3 20C56.4 70 43.6 30 24.3 30z" stroke-dashoffset="27" stroke-dasharray="202.75,54.25" stroke="black" stroke-width="8"  >
        <animate  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="257; 0" begin="svg1.click" dur="1s" restart="whenNotActive" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
    </path> 
</svg>
```

***Шаг #4.*** Вращение иконки при наведении :hover

Добавляем в условие запуска `begin="svg1.mouseenter" end="svg1.mouseleave"`

```html
<style>
.container {
width:8%;
height:auto;  
background:white;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  
  <path fill="none" d="M24.3 30C11.4 30 5 43.3 5 50s6.4 20 19.3 20c19.3 0 32.1-40 51.4-40C88.6 30 95 43.3 95 50s-6.4 20-19.3 20C56.4 70 43.6 30 24.3 30z" stroke-dashoffset="27" stroke-dasharray="202.75,54.25" stroke="black" stroke-width="8"  >
        <animate  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="257; 0" begin="svg1.mouseenter" end="svg1.mouseleave" dur="1s" restart="whenNotActive" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
    </path> 
</svg>
```

### Вариант анимации CSS

При разработке варианта анимации SVG были вычислены необходимые значения параметров атрибутов `stroke-dasharray:202.75,54.25;` и `stroke-dashoffset`

Остается их перенести в CSS правила:

```css
.container {
width:8%;
height:auto;  
background:white;
}

#eight {
fill:none;
stroke:black;
stroke-width:8;
stroke-dasharray:202.75,54.25;
stroke-dashoffset:27px;
}
#svg1:hover #eight {
fill:#dedede;
animation:move 1s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes move {
0% {stroke-dashoffset:27px;}
100% {stroke-dashoffset:257px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  
  <path id="eight" fill="none" d="M24.3 30C11.4 30 5 43.3 5 50s6.4 20 19.3 20c19.3 0 32.1-40 51.4-40C88.6 30 95 43.3 95 50s-6.4 20-19.3 20C56.4 70 43.6 30 24.3 30z" />
</svg>
```